# React-router: how to handle more complex navigation workflows (like, with popups...)

Tags: react-router, browser-history, html5-history

I have an application where you can display 2 kind of content.

There are 3 "main content" pages, which have the urls:

- `/` (root)
- `/favorites`
- `/timeline`

There is also a settings popup. It goes on top of the "main content". I should be able to deep-link to this setting popup directly. Opening that link directly (like, from an email) should lead to the content displayed for the root `/` in the background with the settings popup opened in the foreground.

When the settings popup gets closed, it should not affect main content that was under the popup. Url should take back its previous value (the one of the main content: one of `/` `/favorites` or `/timeline`)

## Usecase: being somewhere, opening the settings popup, and then closing it.

- Be on `/favorites`
- Click on `/settings` link
- Settings popup should open
- Click on close button in settings popup
- Settings popup should close and url should be `/favorites`

I'm having trouble implementing this. I've tried to use `history.goBack()` but it is actually not what I want. On close I don't want to go back, but I actually want to push a new `/favorites` entry into the history.

Also, using `goBack` means that if the user comes directly from link `/settings`, then there's nowhere to go back because there's no back history entry...

I'm also trying to see how I could use `history.push()` but it seems a bit unnatural to me (and very tightly coupled!) that my settings popup could have to do something like `history.push("/favorites")` to close itself...

Any idea on how to solve this problem in an idiomatic way?